# How to get the active document info/text in word, through office JS API

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, add-in, word-addins

I want to get the current active document info/text, which user is able to see on screen.
Can we achive it throgh Word JS API? Or is there any other way to get the current/active page in word for JS Addins.

Answer (score 0):

I think no way to get the current/active page you can get `selection`

[see selection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.section?view=word-js-preview)

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
  // Get the currently active document.
  var document = context.document;

  // Load the body of the document to access its text.
  var body = document.body;
  body.load("text");

  return context.sync().then(function () {
    // Access the text of the document's body.
    var text = body.text;

    // Do something with the text.
    console.log("Text from the active document: " + text);
  });
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```